# How do I load the vlcj library?

Tags: java, vlc, vlcj

I am trying to play youtube video using vlcj.
`"NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName()," C:\\Program Files \\VideoLAN\\VLC");"` 
So I am trying to load a library using this code.

However, the libvlc.dll and libvlccore.dll files could not be loaded due to an error.

`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load the native library.

The error was "Unable to load library 'libvlc': Native library (win32-x86-64/libvlc.dll) not found in resource path ([file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/D:/project/AnimalCrossing/mod/build/classes/main/, file:/D:/project/AnimalCrossing/mod/build/resources/main/, file:/D:/project/AnimalCrossing/mod/libs/slf4j-api-1.7.9.jar, file:/D:/project/AnimalCrossing/mod/libs/vlcj.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/minecraft/deobfedDeps/compileDummy.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/minecraft/deobfedDeps/providedDummy.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2847/snapshot/20171003/forgeSrc-1.12.2-14.23.5.2847.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d/jsr305-3.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mojang/patchy/1.1/aef610b34a1be37fa851825f12372b78424d8903/patchy-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/oshi-project/oshi-core/1.1/9ddf7b048a8d701be231c0f4f95fd986198fd2d8/oshi-core-1.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.4.0/cb208278274bf12ebdb56c61bd7407e6f774d65a/jna-4.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.dev.jna/platform/3.4.0/e3f70017be8100d3d6923f50b3d2ee17714e9c13/platform-3.4.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.ibm.icu/icu4j-core-mojang/51.2/63d216a9311cca6be337c1e458e587f99d382b84/icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.3/cdd846cfc4e0f7eefafc02c0f5dce32b9303aa2a/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-all/4.1.9.Final/97860965d6a0a6b98e7f569f3f966727b8db75/netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/21.0/3a3d111be1be1b745edfa7d91678a12d7ed38709/guava-21.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.5/6c6c702c89bfff3cd9e80b04d668c5e190d588c6/commons-lang3-3.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.5/2852e6e05fbb95076fc091f6d1780f1f8fe35e0f/commons-io-2.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/4b95f4897fa13f2cd904aee711aeafc0c5295cd8/commons-codec-1.10.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.jutils/jutils/1.0.0/e12fe1fda814bd348c1579329c86943d2cd3c6a6/jutils-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/c4ba5371a29ac9b2ad6129b1d39ea38750043eff/gson-2.8.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mojang/authlib/1.5.25/9834cdf236c22e84b946bba989e2f94ef5897c3c/authlib-1.5.25.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mojang/realms/1.10.22/bd0dccebdf3744c75f1ca20063f16e8f7d5e663f/realms-1.10.22.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.8.1/a698750c16740fd5b3871425f4cb3bbaa87f529d/commons-compress-1.8.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.3/18f4247ff4572a074444572cee34647c43e7c9c7/httpclient-4.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3.2/31fbbff1ddbf98f3aa7377c94d33b0447c646b6e/httpcore-4.3.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/it.unimi.dsi/fastutil/7.1.0/9835253257524c1be7ab50c057aa2d418fb72082/fastutil-7.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.8.1/e801d13612e22cad62a3f4f3fe7fdbe6334a8e72/log4j-api-2.8.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.8.1/4ac28ff2f1ddf05dae3043a190451e8c46b73c31/log4j-core-2.8.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.mojang/text2speech/1.10.3/48fd510879dff266c3815947de66e3d4809f8668/text2speech-1.10.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minecraft/launchwrapper/1.12/111e7bea9c968cdb3d06ef4632bf7ff0824d0f36/launchwrapper-1.12.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jline/jline/3.5.1/51800e9d7a13608894a5a28eed0f5c7fa2f300fb/jline-3.5.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm-debug-all/5.2/3354e11e2b34215f06dab629ab88e06aca477c19/asm-debug-all-5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/2.3.3/ed62e9fc709ca0f2ff1a3220daa8b70a2870078e/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/config/1.2.1/f771f71fdae3df231bcd54d5ca2d57f0bf93f467/config-1.2.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-actors-migration_2.11/1.1.0/dfa8bc42b181d5b9f1a5dd147f8ae308b893eb6f/scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.11.1/56ea2e6c025e0821f28d73ca271218b8dd04926a/scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang.plugins/scala-continuations-library_2.11/1.0.2/e517c53a7e9acd6b1668c5a35eccbaa3bab9aac/scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang.plugins/scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1/1.0.2/f361a3283452c57fa30c1ee69448995de23c60f7/scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.1/e11da23da3eabab9f4777b9220e60d44c1aab6a/scala-library-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/1.0.1/f05d7345bf5a58924f2837c6c1f4d73a938e1ff0/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.11.1/6580347e61cc7f8e802941e7fde40fa83b8badeb/scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-swing_2.11/1.0.1/b1cdd92bd47b1e1837139c1c53020e86bb9112ae/scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.2/820fbca7e524b530fdadc594c39d49a21ea0337e/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/lzma/lzma/0.0.1/521616dc7487b42bef0e803bd2fa3faf668101d7/lzma-0.0.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.sf.trove4j/trove4j/3.0.3/42ccaf4761f0dfdfa805c9e340d99a755907e2dd/trove4j-3.0.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact/3.5.3/7dc72b6d6d8a6dced3d294ed54c2cc3515ade9f4/maven-artifact-3.5.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.paulscode/codecjorbis/20101023/c73b5636faf089d9f00e8732a829577de25237ee/codecjorbis-20101023.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.paulscode/codecwav/20101023/12f031cfe88fef5c1dd36c563c0a3a69bd7261da/codecwav-20101023.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.paulscode/libraryjavasound/20101123/5c5e304366f75f9eaa2e8cca546a1fb6109348b3/libraryjavasound-20101123.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.paulscode/librarylwjglopenal/20100824/73e80d0794c39665aec3f62eee88ca91676674ef/librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.paulscode/soundsystem/20120107/419c05fe9be71f792b2d76cfc9b67f1ed0fec7f6/soundsystem-20120107.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.jinput/jinput/2.0.5/39c7796b469a600f72380316f6b1f11db6c2c7c4/jinput-2.0.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/697517568c68e78ae0b4544145af031c81082dfe/lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/d51a7c040a721d13efdfbd34f8b257b2df882ad0/lwjgl_util-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/java3d/vecmath/1.5.2/79846ba34cbd89e2422d74d53752f993dcc2ccaf/vecmath-1.5.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ca.weblite/java-objc-bridge/1.0.0/6ef160c3133a78de015830860197602ca1c855d3/java-objc-bridge-1.0.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.0/8ccfb6541de179bb1c4d45cf414acee069b7f78b/scala-actors-2.11.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.plexus/plexus-utils/3.1.0/60eecb6f15abdb1c653ad80abaac6fe188b3feaa/plexus-utils-3.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/7ff832a6eb9ab6a767f1ade2b548092d0fa64795/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/385ee093e01f587f30ee1c8a2ee7d408fd732e16/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.java.jinput/jinput-platform/2.0.5/53f9c919f34d2ca9de8c51fc4e1e8282029a9232/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/b84d5102b9dbfabfeb5e43c7e2828d98a7fc80e0/lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-windows.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/931074f46c795d2f7b30ed6395df5715cfd7675b/lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-linux.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.lwjgl.lwjgl/lwjgl-platform/2.9.4-nightly-20150209/bcab850f8f487c3f4c4dbabde778bb82bd1a40ed/lwjgl-platform-2.9.4-nightly-20150209-natives-osx.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.gradle/caches/minecraft/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.12.2-14.23.5.2847/start/, file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Community%20Edition%202019.3.1/lib/idea_rt.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.IdeaIC2019.3/system/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar, file:/C:/Users/gustj/.IdeaIC2019.3/system/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar, asmgen:/])".

The required native libraries are named "libvlc.dll" and "libvlccore.dll".

In the text below <libvlc-path> represents the name of the directory containing "libvlc.dll" and "libvlccore.dll"...

There are a number of different ways to specify where to find the native libraries:
 1. Include NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "<libvlc-path>"); at the start of your application code.
 2. Include System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "<libvlc-path>"); at the start of your application code.
 3. Specify -Djna.library.path=<libvlc-path> on the command-line when starting your application.
 4. Add <libvlc-path> to the system search path (and reboot).

If this still does not work, then it may be necessary to explicitly add the native library directory to the operating
system configuration - e.g. on Linux this might mean setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, or adding
configuration to the "/etc/ld.so.conf" file or the "/etc/ld.so.conf.d" directory. Of these options, setting
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the only one that would not require root privileges.

Finally, it is not possible to mix CPU architectures - it is not possible for a 64-bit Java Virtual Machine to load
32-bit native libraries.

More information may be available in the log.
```

`

I installed 64-bit 1.8.0_181 jvm, jre, and vlc is also 64-bit installed in the "C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC" folder. and I use vlcj 3.11.0, jna 4.4.0, jna-platform 3.4.0 version. how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain your VLC is 64 bit? And are you also certain that your application is using your 64 bit JVM when you run it?

Comment: I fixed that problem. Please see new questions.